# Diamond shaped map: converting tile number to coordinates and back

Tags: mathematics, maps, coordinates

I have a diamond shaped map that is displayed as follows:

```
*  *  *  0  1  *  *  *
*  *  2  3  4  5  *  *
*  6  7  8  9 10 11  *
12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
* 28 29 30 31 32 33  *
*  * 34 35 36 37  *  *
*  *  * 38 39  *  *  *
```

The tiles are stored as a uni-dimensional array in a file. So, I need to convert from tile number to coordinates, so I can make an array of arrays `map[i][j]`. I want to convert the tile number to its coordinates in the `map` (i, j) and back.

To do this, I have simplified it to this form (all tiles flushed to the left):

```
   j  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
i 
0     0  1  *  *  *  *  *  *
1     2  3  4  5  *  *  *  *
2     6  7  8  9 10 11  *  *
3    12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
4    20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
5    28 29 30 31 32 33  *  *
6    34 35 36 37  *  *  *  *
7    38 39  *  *  *  *  *  *
```

I have managed to convert a coordinate to its tile number like so:

```
def get_tile_number(i, j):
    # Given a map width and height n:
    if i < (n/2):
        number = i*(i+1) + j
    else:
        number = (2*((n/2)*((n/2)+1))) - ((n-i)*(n-i+1))) + j

So:
get_tile_number(0, 0) -> 0;
get_tile_number(6, 0) -> 34;
```

However, I cannot figure out to go back to the coordinates from the tile numbers, because I have trouble with distilling the i parameter from the tile number.

I have tried googling with terms like "diamond shaped map tile numbers coordinates convert", but no luck.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

## Solution

Based on Ed Marty's answer, the formula looks as follows:

```
def get_ij(tile_number):
    n_serialized_tiles = (2*((n/2)*((n/2)+1)))
    if tile_number < n_serialized_tiles/2: # If before the halfway point of the diamond
        i = math.floor(0.5 * ((math.sqrt((4 * tile_number) + 1)) - 1))
    else:
        i = math.floor(n- (0.5 * ((math.sqrt((4 * ((2 * ((n/ 2) * ((n/ 2) + 1))) - tile_number)) + 1)) - 1)))
```

This finds the i component, after which I can find j by imputing `get_tile_number(i, j=0)` in the previous formula which gets me the tile_number at the start of that row. I then subtract the real tile_number from that number to get j `j = tile_number - get_tile_number(i, j = 0)`.

Comment: In your example, `n = 8` so for (i, j) = (0, 3), `if ( i < n/2 )` passes, and `number = i*(i+1) + j` gives `0 * (1) + 3 = 3`, so I don't know how `(0, 3) -> 0` in this example. Is there something missing from the code or from the description?

Comment: @DMGregory oops, I see my mistake, because in serialized form (array of arrays), all tiles should be flushed to the left. Edited and fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it out in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences and found [this one](https://oeis.org/A259361) for the top half of the diamond:

```
i = floor((-1 + sqrt(1+4*number))/2)
```

The bottom half just needs to be reversed, like you’ve already done when going the other way.

Comment: I would have never thought of visiting the OEIS for this, what an amazing resource.

Comment: Hint: you can also derive this formula by taking your formula for the number at the start of a row, `number = i * (i + 1)`, and rearranging it to solve for `i` using our good old friend the quadratic formula.